# Where sysv-rc-conf gets information about daemons?

Tags: debian, init-script, sysvinit

Recently I deleted an init-script of my program both from filesystem and with `update-rc.d`:

```
update-rc.d foobar remove
```

But `sysv-rc-conf` still lists it, though I can't see links in `/etc/rc*` directories (`for dir in /etc/rc*; do find $dir -name '*foobar*'; done`). Am I doing it wrong? Is it expected behavior?